# Why function not passed as reference in the eventlistener in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, ref

I am using functional components in ReactJS.

```js
const [showState, setState] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
  }
}, []);

function handleClick(event) {
  console.log(showState);
};

function toggleState() {
  setState(true);
}
return ( <
  button onClick = {
    toggleState
  } > Toggle < /button>
)
```

When I toggle the state by pressing the button, after that when I trigger click event (`handleClick` function) by clicking somewhere, Console shows "undefined". But isn't the `handleClick` function passed as reference to the click eventListener, when the state change through toggle, it should display "true" in the console.

Comment: Try disabling `useCapture` by passing `false` to your `addEventListener`.

Comment: @bertdida It doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

When you create function `handleClick` it capture value of `showState` via closure, and this value is undefined on the first render. But when you call `toggleState`, React doesn't change value of `showState`, instead it re-renders component with new value and a new instance of `handleClick` is created, with captured new value. However global listener still store old version of a function with `undefined`.

You can achieve desired result either with `useRef` or by wrapping `handleClick` into `useCallback` and adding it as a dependency to `useEffect`.

`useRef` allow you to persist reference between renders:

```js
const showState = useRef();

function handleClick(event) {
  console.log(showState.current);
};

function toggleState() {
  showState.current = true;
}
```

However, you should keep in mind that `useRef` doesn't trigger re-render.

And with `useCallback`:

```js
const [showState, setState] = useState();

const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
  console.log(showState);
}, [showState]);

useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
  }
}, [handleClick]);
```

This way each time `showState` changes new instance of `handleClick` created, with new value in a closure, and `useEffect` is triggered re-attaching event listener.

Comment: [Works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-kirch-8vi9e?file=/src/App.js)